# PasteboardResolvePromises API change: Porting from SDK MacOSX 10.11 to 10.12

Tags: objective-c, macos

After porting my code from MacOSX10.11 SDK to MacOSX10.12 SDK, I am getting following error:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

here:

```
PasteboardResolvePromises(kPasteboardResolveAllPromises)
```

Here, kPasteboardResolveAllPromises is NULL which means that all promises on all global pasteboard resources currently owned by this application will be resolved.

However, Apple changed this API by making it require pass Non null arguments to it.

You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOS10_12/Swift/ApplicationServices.html).

Interestingly, Apple din't update the documentation for the function, where it still says:

```
#define kPasteboardResolveAllPromises           (PasteboardRef)NULL
/*
 *  PasteboardResolvePromises()
 *  
 *  Summary:
 *    Resolves promises on the provided local pasteboard reference. If
 *    multiple local pasteboard references to the same global
 *    pasteboard resource exist, only those promises made through the
 *    provided reference are resolved.
 *  
 *  Mac OS X threading:
 *    Not thread safe
 *  
 *  Parameters:
 *    
 *    inPasteboard:
 *      The local pasteboard reference for which promises will be
 *      resolved. Passing kPasteboardResolveAllPromises, or NULL, will
 *      cause all promises on all global pasteboard resources currently
 *      owned by this application to be resolved.
 *  
 *  Result:
 *    An operating system result code.
 *  
 *  Availability:
 *    Mac OS X:         in version 10.3 and later in ApplicationServices.framework
 *    CarbonLib:        not available in CarbonLib 1.x, is available on Mac OS X version 10.3 and later
 *    Non-Carbon CFM:   not available
 */
extern OSStatus 
PasteboardResolvePromises(PasteboardRef inPasteboard)         AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_3_AND_LATER;
```

My question is: How do I do the same operation as done by

```
PasteboardResolvePromises(kPasteboardResolveAllPromises)
```